# Filling "implied missing values" in a data frame that has varying observations per time unit

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr

I have a large dataset with spatiotemporal data. Each set of coordinates are associated with an id (player id in a computer game). Unfortunately the coordinates for each id aren't logged at every time unit. If a reading is not available for a specific id at x time stamp, then that row was entirely omitted from the dataset rather than logged as NA.

I would like to have the same exact amount of observations per time unit as there are unique ids (i.e. inserting "implied missing NAs"). On time units where ids are missing, they should be inserted as new rows with NAs as their coordinates.

Here's a dummy dataset to illustrate:

```
time <- c(10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15)
id <- c(1,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,4,5,6,3,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,4,5)
x <- c(128,128,64,64,124,128,120,68,64,64,122,71,65,64,112,74,116,114,113,73,70,70,111,75,70)
y <- c(128,128,64,66,125,128,124,66,67,64,124,67,71,68,113,68,115,119,113,76,69,77,116,80,82)

spatiodf <- as.data.frame(cbind(time, id, x, y))


   time id   x   y
1    10  1 128 128
2    10  3 128 128
3    10  4  64  64
4    10  5  64  66
5    11  1 124 125
6    11  2 128 128
7    11  3 120 124
8    11  4  68  66
9    11  5  64  67
10   11  6  64  64
11   12  1 118 123
12   12  2 122 124
13   12  4  71  67
14   12  5  65  71
15   12  6  64  68
16   13  3 112 113
17   13  6  74  68
18   14  1 116 115
19   14  2 114 119
20   14  3 113 113
21   14  4  73  76
22   14  5  70  69
23   14  6  70  77
24   15  2 111 116
25   15  4  75  80
26   15  5  70  82
```

From the above output I would like to get to the following below output where the data frame was recreated with each time unit having an equal amount of observations (and NA values were manually inserted into rows that had missing values).

```
time <- rep(10:15, each = 6)
id <- rep(1:6, times = 6)
x <- c(128,NA,128,64,64,NA,124,128,120,68,64,64,NA,122,NA,71,65,64,NA,NA,112,NA,NA,74,116,114,113,73,70,70,NA,111,NA,75,70,NA)
y <- c(128,NA,128,64,66,NA,125,128,124,66,67,64,NA,124,NA,67,71,68,NA,NA,113,NA,NA,68,115,119,113,76,69,77,NA,116,NA,80,82,NA)

spatiodf_equal_obs <- as.data.frame(cbind(time, id, x, y))

library(dplyr)
spatiodf_equal_obs %>% 
  arrange(id)

   time id   x   y
1    10  1 128 128
2    11  1 124 125
3    12  1  NA  NA
4    13  1  NA  NA
5    14  1 116 115
6    15  1  NA  NA
7    10  2  NA  NA
8    11  2 128 128
9    12  2 122 124
10   13  2  NA  NA
11   14  2 114 119
12   15  2 111 116
13   10  3 128 128
14   11  3 120 124
15   12  3  NA  NA
16   13  3 112 113
17   14  3 113 113
18   15  3  NA  NA
19   10  4  64  64
20   11  4  68  66
21   12  4  71  67
22   13  4  NA  NA
23   14  4  73  76
24   15  4  75  80
25   10  5  64  66
26   11  5  64  67
27   12  5  65  71
28   13  5  NA  NA
29   14  5  70  69
30   15  5  70  82
31   10  6  NA  NA
32   11  6  64  64
33   12  6  64  68
34   13  6  74  68
35   14  6  70  77
36   15  6  NA  NA
```

The reason the data needs to be in the above format is because I want to be able to fill in the NA values with the nearest available previous or following entry from the same id. Once we have the dataframe in the above output that can be done using fill() from tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
res <- spatiodf_equal_obs %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(x, y, .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(x, y, .direction = "up")
```

I've tried a lot of combinations of spreading, gathering (and trickery with creating new dataframes to merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)). I can't seem to figure out how to go from that first data frame to the second one though.

The final output should look like this:

```
   time id   x   y
1    10  1 128 128
2    11  1 124 125
3    12  1 124 125
4    13  1 124 125
5    14  1 116 115
6    15  1 116 115
7    10  2 128 128
8    11  2 128 128
9    12  2 122 124
10   13  2 122 124
11   14  2 114 119
12   15  2 111 116
13   10  3 128 128
14   11  3 120 124
15   12  3 120 124
16   13  3 112 113
17   14  3 113 113
18   15  3 113 113
19   10  4  64  64
20   11  4  68  66
21   12  4  71  67
22   13  4  71  67
23   14  4  73  76
24   15  4  75  80
25   10  5  64  66
26   11  5  64  67
27   12  5  65  71
28   13  5  65  71
29   14  5  70  69
30   15  5  70  82
31   10  6  64  64
32   11  6  64  64
33   12  6  64  68
34   13  6  74  68
35   14  6  70  77
36   15  6  70  77
```

Comment: `tidyr::complete(spatiodf, time, id)` will give `spatiodf_equal_obs` with the missing values. But using the data table rolling join with `roll = 'nearest'` is gets you all the way there. @Frank post as answer?

Comment: Fyi, your `fill` command does not work correctly, leaving all id 1 with time 10, all id 2 with time 11, and so on.

Comment: My bad Frank. I tried to simplify the repetition sequence of id and got it wrong in an edit. It should be `id <- rep(1:6, times = 6)`.

The example should be correct now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fill in gaps with values taken from the nearest row, you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(spatiodf)

resDT = spatiodf[
  CJ(id = id, time = min(time):max(time), unique = TRUE), on=.(id, time), roll="nearest"
]

# verify
fsetequal(data.table(res), resDT) # TRUE
```

*How it works*

- `setDT` converts to a data.table in place, so no `<-` is needed.
- `DT[i, on=, roll=]` uses `i` to look up rows in `DT`, rolling each `i` to a row in `DT`. The "roll" is done on the final column in `on=`.
- `CJ(a, b, unique = TRUE)` returns all combos of `a` and `b`, like `expand.grid` in base.

Comment: Could you take a second look at my question now that I've edited it to include the final result I'm looking for. I've tried your solution but it seems to jumble up the order on some observation-id pairs. 

I tried to construct the example data in a way where id 1-3 should all have coordinates in the 112-128 span and the ids 4-6 should have coordinates in the 64-80 range. I apologize for messing up one of the previous edits to confuse you.

Comment: @Lauler Yeah, I made a mistake. The order of the columns in `on=` matters when using `roll` and I had it the wrong way around. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you know if `roll="nearest"` carries the nearest above value forward first if the prevailing and next value are equal distance to the NA? What's the priority when an NA has values both above and below it that are equally close? Also reading the data.table documentation I'm thinking `roll = +Inf` followed by `roll = -Inf` might be the equivalent to my dplyr example (fill in the downwards direction first, and then fill in the remaining NAs in the upwards direction). I don't have enough successive NAs in my example to cause the methods to differ in the example provided.

Comment: A simple test suggests it rolls down: `data.table(a = c(1L,3L), b = c(1, 3))[.(2), on=.(a), roll="nearest"]` and same if `on=.(b)` so integers and floats both get that treatment. Yeah, I think you're right that you'd need two rolls for that. I didn't really grok what you were doing there since I don't know tidyr. You might want to post an example with more NAs as a new question if you're not sure (which is the usual etiquette after an answer is posted here on SO).

Comment: Alright. Updated my example above adding an extra NA so that there are two consecutive NAs on one of the ids. New to SO, sorry for breaking etiquette. It makes sense you shouldn't edit your question after someone has answered (hadn't occurred to me before this comment though). I should be able to do two rolls with your example.